# Updating options / config in open Bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am upgrading a modal from Bootstrap 3 to 4. I have some code which will update the options (specifically the backdrop and keyboard options) of an open modal. In Bootstrap 3 I had accomplished this by running:

```
$('.modal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = newBackdropValue;
$('.modal').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = newKeyboardValue;
```

When I upgraded this to Bootstrap 4 I got the error that `options` was undefined. I then tried moving this to use `_config` as that seems to where these options are now housed but it didn't actually update the behavior of the modal.

In looking into the Bootstrap 4 code I noticed that on show it calls the `_setEscapeEvent` which seems to put a listener on the keyboard but I couldn't find public functions which removed this listener.

Would appreciate any insights into how people had done this before I start rooting around and trying to use private methods on the Modal.

Answer (score 0):

for disable

```
$('#modal').off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal');
```

for enable

```
$('#modal').on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 27) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#detailselector').modal('hide')
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `_config` object in the data to update the modal. Just make sure it's done before the modal is shown...

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/DhB7TXVdfc

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(){
    // change the options that were set in data-attributes
    $('#myModal').data("bs.modal")._config.backdrop = false;
    $('#myModal').data("bs.modal")._config.keyboard = false;
});
```

Remember too that the modal must have `tabindex="-1"` in order for the ESC keyboard option to work!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but this is specifically asking about a modal which has already been opened. I am able to set these two fields via the `show` call when I show the modal but need to be able to update this based on new state while the modal is already opened.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Your demo doesn't work. I can still exit with ESC/Clicking outside.

Comment: @l3fty The demo works fine in Chrome. Which browser/env are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest Firefox, it does look like Chrome does work for me.